# Sugarcrm 7 Custom view with tabs

Tags: sugarcrm, bootstrap-tabs

i implement the following custom view

```
<div class="tabbable">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" data-target="tab1">Section 1</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" data-target="tab2">Section 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
            <p>I'm in Section 1.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
            <p>Howdy, I'm in Section 2.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $( function() {
        $('.nav-tabs a').click(function(){
            console.log(this);
            $(this).tab('show');
        });
    } );
</script>
```

The tabs are showing correctly but when i click tab2 the tab is not changing to content of of tab2. Console.log is shown. Any help please ?

Answer (score 0):

The `IDs` provided in `data-target` are missing a leading `#` each.
Values of the `data-target` attribute are parsed as jquery selectors.

```
<li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" data-target="#tab1">Section 1</a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="tab" data-target="#tab2">Section 2</a></li>
```